# Executing Javascript to populate a drop down before HTML page loads

Tags: javascript

I have 2 Drop Downs in a HTML form. The first dropdown needs to be populated with a list of usernames present in the DATABASE.

Secondly, Depending upon the selection made in the first drop down, I then need to run another JS script to make another call to the DB to retrieve the list of associated addresses to that username.

Can you please let me know whats the best way to achieve this objective? 
1) How can I run a JSscript before the HTML form loads to return that list? 
2) Should I get both the usernames and associated addresses in one Db call or just get the usernames first and then use onChange event on the first dropdown to execute the second call?

Any code would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well if you have all the info in same table then why dont you get all data in one go by querying as to the DB and then sort and put up data in the elements the way you want.
the other way will need to query DB 2 times.

Comment: I suppose querying the Db once makes sense but then how do I populate the other drop down depending upon the selection in the first drop down. I can currenlty get all the usernames in a buffered string where each new username is comma separated.

Comment: for drop down lists ther is the value property, you can check which option was selected, then with some if statements you can determine which drop down menu to show

Comment: The data resides in 2 different tables:

1) Users table for Username, UserID (that are active) 

2) Address table contains UserID and AddressID) 

So, usernames are displayed in the first dropdpwn list and depending on the username selected, the associated UserID will be then used to query Address table to get the addressID for that userID.

Comment: then you wil definately have to query twice right!! depending on the value of selected drop down menu. so on selection populate your another drop down with the required fields

Answer (score 0):

```
here you can create your HTML to server call OR you can make HTML locally.
i have created options for selectbox at server and innerhtml to locally.

<select id="selectbox1" onchange="getData(this)"></select>
<select id="selectbox1"></select>

$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/getUsername.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#selectbox1').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});

});

function getData(selData) {

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/getSecoundCall.php?id='+selData,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#selectbox2').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});

}
```